# Cambiar Backcolor de tabla responsive en ejecución

Tags: genexus

GXU17 U3: En un web panel, tengo una tabla responsive.
Si a la misma le quiero cambiar en ejecución el BackColor, de la forma:

```
Table1.BackColor = RGB(255,0,0)
```

No funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si a la misma le asigno una clase que tiene BackColor red, de la forma

```
Table1.Class = ThemeClass:TableFondoRojo
```

Si funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es lo que impide cambiar el color en ejecución con .Backcolor? ¿Es un bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

por lo que vi es un error conocido y que ya se encuentra reportado al equipo de Desarrollo de GeneXus.

Te diría que la forma de resolverlo que tienes al día de hoy, es la que estás utilizadno, es decir, hacer uso del Theme para asignar una clase que cambie el color.

Comment: De acuerdo, el problema es que el usuario puede elegir el color de varios elementos de la pantalla con ColorSelector, y el mismo se guarda en BD en Hexadecimal.
Por lo tanto, entiendo que debería hacer 16.777.216 clases si quiero cubrir todos los colores.
Me contactaré con la gente de Genexus entonces.